# Null conditional in Motoko?

Tags: arrays, dfinity, motoko

Getting the following error:

```
expression of type
  ?Product/798
cannot produce expected type
  {id : Nat; name : Text; price : Nat; sku : Text}
```

when trying to loop over a list of ids, get the corresponding HashMap value, and add to a new array only if the get() function returns a Product.

```
for (id in productIds.vals()) {
   var product: ?Product = products.products.get(id);

   if (product != null) {
      products_list := Array.append<Product>(products_list, [product]);
   };
};
```

Am I maybe misunderstanding the best way to approach this? It seems like I shouldn't get any errors because if it's not a Product type (which is the "expected type" it references) it should just continue on, right?

Answer (score 1):

The variable `product` is of type `?Product`, but your instantiation of the `Array.append` function expects an array of values of plain type `Product`.

The comparison with `null` does not magically  change the type of the variable. You'll need to pattern-match it with a `switch` to extract the actual value:

```
switch product {
  case (?p) { products_list := Array.append<Product>(products_list, [p]) };
  case null { ...do something else... };
}
```